# Access dockerized Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, firewall, ufw

I have a react app dockerized along with Nginx

```
### First Stage ###
FROM node:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

### Second Stage ###
FROM nginx:alpine

ARG NGINXFILE
COPY ${NGINXFILE} /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 443
```

and this is the Nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # 404 if a file is requested (so the main app isn't served)
    location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

then, on the docker-compose file, port 80 is mapped to 80

```
react-app:
    image: react-app-production:${ENV}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    networks:
      - mern-app
```

On the server side, `ufw` is set to pass all `TCP` traffic of port 80

```
80/tcp                     ALLOW FWD   Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)
```

and I can see the app is listening to port 80

```
docker-pr 16278            root    4u  IPv4  92410      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 16283            root    4u  IPv6  92129      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

But this app is not acceable via browser or when it is pinged.

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to?  What response do you get?  In a tag you hint at AWS; are Amazon security groups a potential consideration here?

Comment: @DavidMaze Security groups allow for HTTP/TCP on port 80 from 0.0.0.0/0 and I am trying to access the Public IPV4 of the server. There is no response pings are lost 100%

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `EC2` configurations that do not allow `HTTP` connection and always redirects to `HTTPS`. I installed an SSL certificate and the problem was solved.